# How long is the S/PDIF preamble?

Tags: audio, digital-audio, audio-codec, spdif, toslink

I have a simple S/PDIF protocol question that I can't find the answer to anywhere. I'm trying to understand the protocol, and everywhere I look says the same thing: The length of a preamble pattern is 8 bits, but the allocated length in the word frame is only 4 bits. Here's an example from an ST application note:

[image]

[image]

Everywhere else I have looked says the same thing too. **How do I reconcile this information? Is the preamble slot 4 or 8 bits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preamble length is 4 unencoded bits  as the whole data frame is 32 unencoded bits.

The preamble length is 8 biphase Manchester encoded time slots as the whole data frame is 64 time slots.

As the preamble violates the bit encoding it can only be represented as 8 encoded symbols and not unencoded bits.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. So you can scan the bitstream for a violation and you know it’ll be a sync point (preamble)?